# Custom checkbox symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

Consider the following `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \draw[line width=3pt,rounded corners] (0.75,1)--(0,1)--(0,0) -- (1,0) -- (1,0.5);
                \draw[xshift=0cm,yshift=0.35cm,line width=3pt] (0.25,0.25)--(0.5,0)--(1,0.5);
            \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I create the same diagram by using coordinate or node definition. I want to convert this into a usable symbol that I can scale at any size, say the current font size and usable in `mathmode`.

I know `fontawesome` has `\faCheckSquareO`, but I designed this since I want full control over the color of the each component of the diagram.

Comment: The easiest wrapper would be putting everything inside `ckbx/.pic` and using it as `pic[scale=2]{ckbx}`. I am not sure what kind of usage is in your mind though.

Comment: @Symbol1 A scaleable diagram relative to the current font size, say `\large` or `\footnotesize`

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `\newcommand\ckbx[1][]{
 \tikz[baseline=-.5ex,#1]{
  \draw circle(1em);
 }
}
\foreach\size in{\huge,\Large,\normalsize,\footnotesize,\tiny}{
 \par\noindent\size
 Size is {\ttfamily\expandafter\string\size}.
 Plain \ckbx.
 Red \ckbx[red].
 Rescaled \ckbx[xscale=.5].
}`

Comment: @Symbol1 Seems to be right. Love your style of generalizing. :)

Comment: @Symbol1 You should post an answer!

Comment: I am going to bed. OP is mature enough to give a complete answer.